# Python; count the number of tweets retweeted

Tags: python

I have a Pandas dataframe containing tweets. I want to count the number of tweets that have been retweeted.
This code does not work

```
tweets_retweeted = twitter.apply(lambda x:True if x.retweet_count > 0 else False)
count_of_tweets_retweeted = len(tweets_retweeted[tweets_retweeted == True].index)
```

The error message I get is

> KeyError: ('retweet_count', 'occurred at index created_at')

Comment: Could you include an [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the ability to recreate your example, there are a few things that could be going on.

1. The error is likely coming from the 1st line where you are trying to access the column.
2. You may be passing one column at a time to the apply function rather than one row at a time. Please use axis = 1 to pass each row to see if it works.

Also, just a best practice (in my humble opinion) is to not reference column names with the dot notation. Try to use the bracket notation to differentiate between column names and methods.

Comment: The axis=1 made the difference, it works now. Thank you very much both for the answer and the suggestion for improving my python, a language I am new to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do:

```
j = twitter['retweet_count'] > 0
j.value_counts()
```